# How to setup a simple standalone XC9 instance?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-install-framework

Dear Sitecore Community,

I'm working on a Sitecore 9 solution where we want to start a eCommerce project using Sitecore Experience Commerce 9. Therefore I want to install the Sitecore XC 9 components on a dedicated server for our development environment (to have a shared XC9 instance for the developers).

Sadly, every installation guide I found uses the Sitecore Install Framework (SIF), which expects a local Sitecore installation on the server. But as this server should hold only the XC9 components, I don't want a local installation. I also don't need the Storefront example packages.

I checked some of the installation scripts of the SIF and noticed, that some of the installed services (CommerceAuthoring, CommerceMinions, CommerceOps and CommerceShops) use the same application just with different bindings. Would it be possible, to install just one of them and use it for all the different purposes? As it is a development machine, performance is not the important.

Is there a documentation of the XC9, where I can see how a **minimal** XC9 installation could look like? In my opinion, the SIF script installs a lot of components, that are not absolutely necessary.

Or maybe I'm taking a wrong approach here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "development environment", do you mean, that you want to build multi-server setup for your deployments (e.g. CM server + CD server + XC server) or you mean, that you want to have 1 XC server that will be shared across your Sitecore team (so that your team will not need to install XC on their local machines)?

Comment: The second option. I would like to setup a shared XC server.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Sitecore SIF is the only official way to install XC. You can find installation guide [here](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Installation-Guide/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Installation_Guide(On-Prem).pdf).

Default XC package contains XC Engine installation, Commerce Connect, Default Catalog, Demo SXA Storefront, XC Engine extension VS template and some other things.

You are free to modify the SIF scripts to install only needed components. So you can safely remove demo SXA site especially if you have already existing non-SXA components.

However, I think it will be better to have XC9 installed locally on each developer machine.

Some points for this:

- You will most likely do changes to XC9 engine. So if somebody breaks your XC engine, the whole team will be blocked
- By default, XC engine needs a connection to Sitecore. For some functionalities, it's not the one-way connection from Sitecore to XC Engine, but from Engine to Sitecore as well. (see ContentPolicySet for configuration). Biztools (XC9 admin interface) requires Sitecore to properly render images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into Docker, you could give https://github.com/avivasolutionsnl/sitecore-commerce-docker a try.

In addition, you could use it (the Dockerfiles) as reference of how to get a minimal setup.